# How to correct a leg dysmorphia

Tags: strength

I am currently training my legs at home by doing Bulgarian Split squats 4 times a week.

When I began, I always felt it more on the left quad. It lags behind the right one because the left one is subject to muscle strain.

The left quad is slightly bigger above the knee inside (Vastus Medialis). The total circumference of the leg is 1.5 cm bigger than the right. There is no inflammation, and I can train both legs without much problem.

Now, I like to correct that dysmorphia. I was thinking of increasing the reps range on the right and decreasing it slightly on the left. But since the right one is already stronger, it may increase the gap.

Is there another way to correct the dysmorphia without increasing the strength gap?

Comment: "Dysmorphia" means a psychological disorder where the sufferer believes that their body is wrong or inadequate. It is treated by psychologists. Is that actually what you meant to ask about?

Comment: @DavidScarlett more like a condition in which part of the body is a different shape from normal as stated here : https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dysmorphia

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to just simply work the weaker/smaller side first and copy the same reps/sets on the stronger side.  The weaker side will get more stimulus while the stronger side will get less. They will start to balance out over time as the weaker side gets stronger and the stronger side maintains strength.

For example when doing Bulgarian Split Squats, start with the left leg. Let's say form breaks down at 9 reps on the left leg. Stop and switch to the right leg and do only 9 reps even if you could do 12. Now the left leg has more effective reps in the set and will grow slightly more.